# How do i validate a date using combination of fields using the Struts validator

Tags: java, struts, struts-validation

If i have 3 text fields on a form how can i use the struts validator to check that a compination of all 3 fields should form a valid date.

For example

```
<form action="/test">

  <input type=text name=day> 

  <select name=month>
  <option value=JAN>JAN</option>
  <option value=JAN>JAN</option>
  <option value=JAN>FEB</option>
     ---
    ---
  <option value=DEC>DEC</option>
 </select>

 <input type=text name=year> 

</form>
```

In the struts validator i can do something like this

```
 <field
                property="day"
                depends="required,mask">
                    <arg key="myForm.day"/>
                    <var>
                        <var-name>mask</var-name>
                        <var-value>^[0-9]*$</var-value>
                    </var>
            </field>
```

But how can i check that day+Month+year is a valid date? including Februaries and leap years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the Struts documentation [Struts Validator Guide](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/faqs/validator.html) find the following example

```
Comparing Two Fields
```

This is an example of how you could compare two fields to see if they have the same value. A good example of this is when you are validating a user changing their password and there is the main password field and a confirmation field.

```
<validator name="twofields"
   classname="com.mysite.StrutsValidator"
   method="validateTwoFields"
   msg="errors.twofields"/>

<field property="password"
   depends="required,twofields">
      <arg position="0" key="typeForm.password.displayname"/>
      <var>
         <var-name>secondProperty</var-name>
         <var-value>password2</var-value>
      </var>
```

```
public static boolean validateTwoFields(
Object bean,
ValidatorAction va, 
Field field,
ActionErrors errors,
HttpServletRequest request, 
ServletContext application) {

String value = ValidatorUtils.getValueAsString(
    bean, 
    field.getProperty());
String sProperty2 = field.getVarValue("secondProperty");
String value2 = ValidatorUtils.getValueAsString(
    bean, 
    sProperty2);

if (!GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(value)) {
   try {
      if (!value.equals(value2)) {
         errors.add(field.getKey(),
            Resources.getActionError(
                application,
                request,
                va,
                field));

         return false;
      }
   } catch (Exception e) {
         errors.add(field.getKey(),
            Resources.getActionError(
                application,
                request,
                va,
                field));
         return false;
   }
}

return true;}
```

I think you could be a basis to compare and validate your three fields which together form a correct date

Good Luck.